# How to find and edit the email that sends to users when unblocking their account in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, email

I'm new to CiviCRM + Drupal, and a lot of knowledge of the platform never got passed on in my organization.

Right now, when someone signs up through our CiviCRM, they are de facto blocked in Drupal.
Upon being unblocked, they are sent an email that looks like this:[image: unblock email]

Here's the unblock feature in Drupal "People's" tab I'm talking about:[image: unblock people]

When a user originally signs up through our Civi (before they're unblocked), they get a confirmation email that was customized by our organization, so it is a feature that at one point was able to be edited.

Any suggestions on how I can search this email and edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Config - People - Account Settings. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/config-user.html

Comment: Worked great, thank you!